# Inverting values of raster file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, pixel

I ran a proximity (raster distance) function and I would like to invert the result.

Is there a simple way to do this without converting it back to vector format and editing the attribute table?

Comment: Yes, raster calculator https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html the actual calculation depends on what you mean by *invert*.

Comment: The proximity raster function creates pixels with higher values the further away from the object they are.  I would like to invert those values so the numbers get smaller as they get further.

Comment: Use an n-R calculation where n is a constant and R is you cell value.. where R is small the output is large, where R is large the output is small.

Comment: No worries! I'm glad you got a result. Can you please answer your own question, with screenshots preferably, for the benefit of users in the future who have the same requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. Stimson I used the expression 1000-(raster layer) to get the inverted raster result.  I chose 1000  because it didn't have to be an exact invert and I didn't want negative numbers.  I need to run it through r.cost algorithm which creates an error if there is a negative number.  [image]

If you are wondering what number to use try this link [How to extract pixel value counts from a raster in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83407/how-to-extract-pixel-value-counts-from-a-raster-in-qgis)

Answer (score 4):

Invert values with QGIS Raster Calculator:

```
-1 * "yourRaster@1" +  MAX("yourRaster@1")
```

but `MAX()` is not working properly according to some QGIS Bugs Reports.

Instead of `MAX()` put the maximum value of your raster. Then:

```
-1 * "yourRaster@1" + "put the maximum value of your raster"
```

Cheers