# Cost distance tool to figure out shortest distance over water between 2 points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, cost-path, least-cost, cost-surface

I have multiple points in a bay and I need to figure out the distance of each point to the nearest inlet, without going over land.

I have been told to use the Cost Path or the Cost Distance tool but am very lost. Would my 'input raster' be the inlet or the other points?

I am guessing the input cost raster would be a raster of the body of water?

Do I need to be using the ModelBuilder for this tool, or use the cost path tool first?

Comment: Check out this process.  It's pretty much what you are looking for.  See my comment at the bottom about making it easier to work with.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190640/create-an-optimised-path-between-nodes-avoiding-polygons-entities

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

The below workflow will work (assuming I have understood your requirements):

- Run [Cost Distance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cost-distance.htm)

  - Source = inlets (create a raster or point feature class of *just* the inlets, everything else NoData).
  - Cost = 1 for water, NoData for land.
- Use [Extract Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) to get the least cost distance from each of your points to the nearest inlet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Cost Path as Polyline tool that will give you the output at a line instead of a raster.