# Making path between polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, centroids

I am trying to draw a line (vector layer) of a certain length that that tries as much as possible to dodge the green polygons.

[image]

Assuming a starting point, is there some sort of line centroid algorithm/function already created that I could use?

[image]

Comment: In a raster world you could do a cost route along cells weighted 0 (empty vector coded as 0) while coding the cells that 'were' vector as 100 and create a seperate raster as start and end points and simply convert the result to a vector line (from a raster of a path of cell width of 1)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the best way would be rasterizing your polygon and calculating the best cost-effective route, as proposed here:

[Create an optimised path between nodes avoiding polygons entities](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190640/create-an-optimised-path-between-nodes-avoiding-polygons-entities)